# Transfer table data from SQL Server 2016 to Microsoft Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, sql-server-2016, transfer, azure-synapse

I have an `SQL Server 2016` on-Promises with three tables. 
In total I have over 20,000,000 records. I need to transfer them to `Azure Synapse`.

I have created `ssis` packages to transfer data but I am looking for less expensive way to do that. I transferred just 20000 rows and it costed me about 250$.

Is there any tool or solution for that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to Azure Data Factory?  If so, use that resource.  The link below gives you step by step instructions about how to do everything.

https://marlonribunal.com/copy-data-from-on-premise-sql-server-to-azure-database-using-azure-data-factory/

[image]

I've found Data Factory to be very easy to use and pretty darn fast.  If you want something more command line driven and super, super, super fast, consider using Azure Databricks for this kind of task.  The link below will help you get started with things.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6151/using-azure-databricks-to-query-azure-sql-database/

[image]

Comment: I have access to ADF and Data Bricks. I am looking somethings like restore table?

Comment: Start with ADF.  It's wayyyyy easier to work with compared to Databricks.  ADF is fast and very flexible too.  When you master that, and you want to develop some new skills, start working with Databricks.  If you love coding, eventually you will probably find Databricks easier to use.